# Creating multiple python files with variables set to values from a list

Tags: python-2.7

I need to make a set of python files where each file contains a variable set to a specific value. The values are contained in a list. Say we have two lists of values for two variables (say 3 values each).

```
myVariable1 = 10,11,12
myVariable2 = 100,101,102
```

I need to create three files that each contain these values as such:

```
#file 1
myVariable1 = 10
myVariable2 = 100

#file 2
myVariable1 = 11
myVariable2 = 101

#file 3
myVariable1 = 12
myVariable2 = 102
```

In addition to the these two lines of code, each file will also need to contain additional code that will remain the same for all files.

```
   #file 1
myVariable1 = 10
myVariable2 = 100

print(myVariable1)
print(myVariable2)

#file 2
myVariable1 = 11
myVariable2 = 101

print(myVariable1)
print(myVariable2)

#file 3
myVariable1 = 12
myVariable2 = 102

print(myVariable1)
print(myVariable2)
```

Many thanks! Chris

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most efficient way to do this is to append a row to a file.

```
myCsvRow = [myVariable, 10]
with open('document.csv','a') as fd:
    fd.write(myCsvRow)
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: I think the question asks for a little more than this. Although there hasn't been much effort to show what the user has tried and where issues occurred.

Comment: That is exactly why I said this. I don't want to do the guys project for him. I feel that you won't learn that way.